# Create a new variable based on 4 other variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in Python called **df1** where I have 4 dichotomous variables called Ordering_1; Ordering_2, Ordering_3, Ordering_4 with True/False values.

I need to create a variable called **Clean**, which is based on the 4 other variables. Meaning, when Ordering_1 == True, then Clean == Ordering_1, when Ordering_2==True, then Clean == Ordering_2. Then Clean would be a combination of all the true values from Ordering_1; Ordering_2, Ordering_3, Ordering_4.

[Here is an example of how I would like the variable Clean to be:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u1jK.jpg)

I have tried the below code but it does not work:
df1[Clean] = df1[Ordering_1] + df1[Ordering_1] + df1[Ordering_1] + df1[Ordering_1]

Would anyone please be able to help me how to do this in python?

Comment: Are there only one `True`s per row?

Comment: No there are more than one True and False values per variable.

Answer (score 1):

Universal solution if there are multiple `True`s per rows - filter columns by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and then use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) for matrix multiplication:

```
df1 = df.filter(like='Ordering_')

df['Clean'] = df1.dot(df1.columns + ',').str.strip(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one "True" value per row you can use the booleans of each column "Ordering_1", "Ordering_2", etc. and the df1.loc.

Note that this is what you get with df1.Ordering_1:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: Ordering_1, dtype: bool

With df1.loc you can use it to filter on the "True" rows, in this case only row 0:
[image]

So you can code this:

1. Create a new blank "clean" column:
   df1["clean"]=""
2. Set the rows where the series df.Ordering_1 = True to "Ordering_1":
   df1.loc[df1.Ordering_1,["clean"]] = "Ordering_1"
   [image]
3. Proceed with the remaining columns in the same way.